# App.Config on Winforms is getting reinstalled

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows application installed and working perfectly fine.

Something weird came up, the test scenario is if I rename the config file from the original name which is:

**Model Label PC Client.exe.config**

...to:

**xxxModel Label PC Client.exe.config**

...and click the .EXE file on the application folder / path where i installed it, it **works as expected**.

But when I clicked the **shortcut** icon of this application on the desktop, it shows a pop up that **installs a new copy of the correct config file name**.

please refer to the screenshot , any idea how to prevent this from happening? or is this really the behavior?

[image: Error]

Comment: MSI mechanism checks if installation is corrupted(and yes, changing file in installation dir is corruption) and then trying to fix ... you should consider different way to store global settings ...... or deploy app as "xcopy" ... if it is one time change then you may generatte settings file at installation

Comment: hi @Selvin thanks for the information. Actually its a test case scenario, where in if the file does not exist on the folder , error message / dialog box should show up. Which is happening when i open the .exe of the application on the installed path. But if I open the shortcut icon then i shows this prompt for installing. is there a way to prevent this when i click the shortcut icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP:

> *"any idea how to prevent this from happening?"*

For installed apps, *it is by design*.  Essentially you have removed an installed file and so the installer tech will kick in to recover it as if nothing happened.

Now technically you could get around that auto-recovery by not using MSI tech to install your app trusting instead on good-ol' XCOPY but then again, renaming/moving/deleting the file may break the app because this time there is no auto-recovery!

Additionally .NET apps expect to find a .config file matching the same name as the executable so you shouldn't go renaming/deleting/moving it in most scenarios.